# problem in Accessing ViewData in javascript+MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am required to assign ViewData["file"]'s value to an html hidden control through javascript/jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You need to have

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("[name=hdnHiddenField]").attr("value",@ViewData["file"]);
   });
</script>
```

and in your view:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdnHiddenField"/>
```

Note that you **cannot** have this script in an external js file.

Comment: $("[name=hdnHiddenField]").attr("value",@ViewData["file"]); this is giving error on firefox console "@ViewData["file"]"

Comment: this script should be inline to view and your view should use razor to work correctly